# Работа с двумя объектами из одной функции

Tags: jquery

```
            <div class="form-group label-floating mt-3 mb-1">
                <label class="control-label">Укажите старый пароль</label>
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="" name="account-old-password" type="text" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group label-floating mt-3 mb-1">
                <label class="control-label">Укажите новый пароль</label>
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="" name="account-new-password" type="text" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
```

Так происходит работа с двумя формами из разных функций

```
$('input[name="account-old-password"]').on('focusout', function () {
   ///
});

$('input[name="account-new-password"]').on('focusout', function () {
  ///
});
```

А как работать с ними из одной функции. Что-то на подобии такого:

```
$('input[name="account-old-password"] input[name="account-new-password"]').on('focusout', function () {
  ///
});
```

И как определить какая именно потеряла focus и является **this**?

Comment: дай им одинаковый уникальный класс и работай через класс. Если хочешь через нейм - укажи через запятую

Comment: А как определить какая именно потеряла focus и является this?

Comment: @ДенисНебесный а это очень надо знать **какая именно** потеряла фокус? Почему?

Comment: @СергейМишин ну а как я без этого буду знать с какой именно формой мне работать и с какой формой закончил работать пользователь?

Comment: @ДенисНебесный  а зачем это знать? что там происходит своебразное в этих формах, что нужно знать? Думаю, стоит больше расписать в вопросе и приложить больше кода, чтобы понять контекст. В текущем случае ответ дан в первом комментарии

Comment: @СергейМишин, далее я описываю то, что должно выполняться из одной функции. Пользователь вводит пароль, когда фокус теряется с первой формы, то происходит проверка второй, если она не заполнена, то фокус переходит к ней. После её заполнение выполняется ajax запрос для сохранения данных. **Всё должно выполняться из одной функции**

Comment: @ДенисНебесный Ты сделай одну функцию `check`, которая будет проверять поля с каким-нибудь атрибутом `required` на нужность заполнения. И вот как раз проверяй `this` того поля, которое не прошло проверку, точнее нужно будет взять `.closest('form')` к которой относится этот проверяемый элемент (http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/Ближайший_подходящий_предок). Туда и фокус будет ставиться. А `check` будет вызываться внутри `focusout`, как уже сказали, где через запятую перечислить элементы триггеры надо

Comment: Твой вариант мне подходит. Но вопрос удалять не буду, просто ради интереса, чтобы на будущее узнать как получить this элемента, который потерял фокус из функции, где несколько триггеров.